# echarts: Is there any way to change the `axisPointer` shadow to a lighter grey shadow?

Tags: javascript, echarts

I am trying to change the default shadow color (when hovering over a bunch of bars for example: https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=bar-label-rotation)

Focusing on this example on this code part:

```
option = {
    color: ['#003366', '#006699', '#4cabce', '#e5323e'],
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis',
        axisPointer: {
            type: 'shadow'
        }
    }, ....... 
       ..............................
       ............................................
```

the `type` variable has 3 options as stated in the documentation: 
https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#grid.tooltip.axisPointer.type

but I couldn't find anything that can control the color of the shadow. 
I want it in a much lighter gray color than it is by default.

Is there any other way to set the shadows color?

I have been exploring echarts.js for a while.. and sadly, except of the fact that all charts graphics are amazing, unfortunately -  I find more cons than pros :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
axisPointer.shadowStyle.color

```
 color: {
        type: 'linear',
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        x2: 0,
        y2: 1,
        colorStops: [{
            offset: 0, color: 'red' // color at 0% position
        }, {
            offset: 1, color: 'blue' // color at 100% position
        }],
        globalCoord: false // false by default
    }
```

It is given in their documentation. Check this out: https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#axisPointer